# Access to Single NPD BookScan Report: Is it possible?

Tags: publishing, sales, traditional-publishing, data

I'm seeking assistance to obtain a single NPD BookScan report for one book. Direct access to a full license is beyond my current needs and budget. If anyone has access or knows a consultant who provides such data, please let me know. I'm open to discussing fair compensation for this service, as there seems to be no one offering this service anywhere. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I am convinced that Circana (formerly NPD) and Nielsen, the operators of BookScan, forbid the resale of their data. Have you contacted [Circana](https://www.circana.com/contact-us/) (for the USA) or [Nielsen](https://nielsenbook.co.uk/contact-us/) (for the rest of the world) and asked them directly? They may sell single data points or offer other deals for the press or science.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm concerned that this may be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - if all you're looking for are the sales figures of a specific book, why not just ask "how can I find the sales figures of this particular book?" We may be able to provide you with an answer that doesn't involve NPD BookScan reports and thus circumvents your current question entirely.

Comment: @F1Krazy , Perhaps. But as far as I know, Circana now has the most comprehensive data on traditional book sales. However, it doesn't offer much flexibility to those who need very limited access (in my case, data for 1 book, one time). So, I'm stuck between paying way more than necessary or finding a consultant willing to offer the service. Knowing that I'm far from being the only one in this situation, I thought other fellow writers could share their experiences on this matter.

Comment: Your best bet is to contact the publisher. If you have a valid reason (like doing scientific research), they may accommodate you. Besides BookScan, there is also [Bookstat](https://bookstat.com/). They claim to have better data than Nielsen. Inquire if they sell single data points.